Should bitcoin-qt and standard-client be synonymous?
Shouldn't bitcoin-qt and standard-client be synonyms? If not, what is the difference (so that the tag-wiki can be filled in)?

Done. Vote here.

Alright, I will suggest it, once I have 1250 reputation. ;)
